# Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (3,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

```
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

i am getting error at this part.Any solution?
Thank You.

Comment: On which dataset are you working on? The issue is between you dataset shape and num_classes.

Comment: @moxy I am working on speech data set downloaded from http://accent.gmu.edu/browse.php and I converted to meta data csv file

Comment: Ok, what is the value  of `num_classes` and `len(y_train[0])`? Can you add the part of your code where you create the dataset and your model? I think the problem can be solved if `num_classes = 3`.

Comment: @moxy value of num_classes is 6 .Yeah i will post the code in this present post

Comment: @moxy I am giving the codes links once check through it please . https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Led5u730Nrh20mM-L48E4ot_K8CIvIGA Thank You